# HTML CSS browser sidebar always visible in website

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

this is the most stupid question here on stackoverflow...

My client would like to have always visibile sidebar in all pages of his website..

Some pages have scrolling, other no, so he see logo and element jump position from one page to another of the scrollbar width ...

so... there is a way to "lock" the scrollbar space, so the he don't see "jump" form one page to another?

thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

forces the scrollbar to be shown always

Answer (score 1):

use fixed position:

```
#sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
}
```

With the above, the container div will always stay 10 pixels from the top and left of the browser window. So when the page scrolls, it will not move.